# Why do weak reference local variables enter the Tenured Generation

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm-hotspot

In the project, it was suddenly found that full gc appeared frequently. After investigation, it was found that a local variable was linked to the global cache through a weak reference, which could not be recycled in the minor gc, resulting in the Tenured Generation.

[class reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLp4f.png)

recurrent code:

JDK:jdk1.8.0_151
JVM args: -Xmx500m -Xms500m

```
public class WeakRefTest {
@Test
public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    Map<Object, ValueObject> map = new WeakHashMap<>();
    while (true) {
        mapPut(map);
        map.size();
    }
}
private void mapPut(Map<Object, ValueObject> map) {
    Object o = new Object();
    map.put(o, new ValueObject(o));
}
private static class ValueObject {
    private Object key;
    private int[] array;
    public ValueObject(Object key) {
        this.key = key;   // [$1] Commenting this line of code is normal (local variables are recycled in the minor gc)
        this.array = new int[100];
    }
}}
```

[memory result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0gJ6.png)
[memory result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPvn7.png)

[comment $1 line of code result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0yBY.png)
[comment $1 line of code result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SvTD.png)

Comment: The documentation of `WeakHashMap` says: "**Implementation note**: The value objects in a WeakHashMap are held by ordinary strong references. Thus care should be taken to ensure that value objects do not strongly refer to their own keys, either directly or indirectly, since that will prevent the keys from being discarded." This means your keys are strongly referenced when you do not comment out $1.

Comment: Weak references only go away when all strong references to their contents are gone.  You're holding a strong reference from the value, which is itself held with a normal strong reference.

Comment: A garbage collector does not collect variables but *objects*. Since you put the object into a map, it is obviously reachable by the map, in other words, an object in heap memory. There is no sense in using the term “local variable” in this context. It’s not the local variable which is linked but the object. Nothing you’ve shown so far, is indicating that the object is “in the Tenured Generation”, not that it matters at all. As others already said, if the object is reachable through the mapped value, it can’t get garbage collected.